# VS2017 Enterprise Code Coverage Doesn't Do It's Job

Tags: visual-studio-2017, code-coverage, mstest

The code coverage tool in VS2017 enterprise no longer shows what application code is covered. Whether I run it on selected tests or all tests, it shows what code in the unit tests are covered, but shows the code actually being tested at 0%. When I first started using the tool it worked just fine and showed application code coverage. I only check coverage occasionally, so I'm not sure when it broke or what I might have done to cause the issue. I'm thinking that there is something in the Registry that is causing it since I haven't been able to find anything in Tools/Options/...

I installed JetBrains dotCoverage and it does the same thing even when I exclude the unit test project from the coverage session. I've tried to repair the VS installation. My next step is uninstall/reinstall. However, unless that cleans up the registry where I think the configuration error is, it will fail to address the problem.

So any suggestions on where I can look to figure this out would be appreciated.